# How to get transient value in validation

Tags: grails

I have the following Domain Class:

```
class UserAccount {
    String userName
    String password
    String confirmPassword

    static transients = ['confirmPassword']

    static constraints = {
        userName blank: false, nullable: false
        password blank: false, nullable: false
        userName(unique: true)
        password(password: true)
        password(blank: false, nullable: false, size:5..20, validator: {password, obj ->
            def confirmPassword= obj.properties['confirmPassword']
            //println(confirmPassword)
            confirmPassword== password ? true : ['invalid.matchingpasswords']
        } )
    }
}
```

In this class i have declared `confirmPassword` as `transients` but confirmPassword prints only a `NULL` when submitting a form.

```
<g:field type="password" name="confirmPassword" required="" value="${userAccountInstance?.confirmPassword}"/>
```

If i remove the `transients`, its working fine but I don't want this value in the Database so i have used `transients`.

Is there another way to do a validation here?

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo, the input field should be named confirmPassword

```
<g:field type="password" name="confirmPassword".../>
```

UPDATE:

make a single constraint for the password:

```
static constraints = {
    password blank: false, password: true, size:5..20, validator: {password, obj ->
        def confirmPassword = obj.confirmPassword
        //println(confirmPassword)
        confirmPassword== password ?: ['invalid.matchingpasswords']
    } )
}
```

Comment: Sorry , it is confirmPassword only .I need to edit the question. actually it was just confirm in my code. i thought confirmPassword will be understandable, so updated .But missed to update that one.

Comment: its working for length validation but not for confirm password.still it return Null  ..

Comment: how do you bind request params to the UserAccount instance? what value does the confirmPassword field have?

Comment: its GORM ... instance will persist the data. confirmpassword is for user to confirm the entered password !! but now with transient it has only NULL